# DeviceIoControl returning ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: c, windows, winapi, ioctl, tun

I'm trying to interface with a driver for creating TUN interfaces (WinTun), but in order to send and receive data from them I need to register a ring buffer. The code I'm using looks something like this (I omitted the part where I create the device with SetupApi, as that seems to be working):

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <winioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define REGISTER_RINGS_IOCTL CTL_CODE(51820U, 0x970U, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_DATA | FILE_WRITE_DATA)

#define BUF_CAPACITY 0x20000
#define BUF_TRAILING 0x10000

typedef struct {
    volatile ULONG Head;
    volatile ULONG Tail;
    volatile LONG Alertable;
    UCHAR Data[BUF_CAPACITY + BUF_TRAILING];
} TUN_RING;

typedef struct {
    ULONG Size;
    UCHAR Data;
} TUN_PACKET;

typedef struct {
    struct {
        ULONG RingSize;
        TUN_RING *Ring;
        HANDLE TailMoved;
    } Send, Receive;
} TUN_REGISTER_RINGS;

int main() {

    HANDLE device = CreateFileW(
        L"\\\\?\\ROOT#NET#0006#{cac88484-7515-4c03-82e6-71a87abac361}",
        // ^^ This comes from the omitted code ^^
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL
    );

    if(device == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("The device does not exist\n");
        return -1;
    }

    TUN_RING Send, Receive = {0};

    TUN_REGISTER_RINGS params = {
        .Send.RingSize = sizeof(TUN_RING),
        .Send.Ring = &Send,
        .Send.TailMoved = CreateEventW(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL),

        .Receive.RingSize = sizeof(TUN_RING),
        .Receive.Ring = &Receive,
        .Receive.TailMoved = CreateEventW(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL),
    };

    DWORD bytes;

    BOOL ret = DeviceIoControl(
        device,
        REGISTER_RINGS_IOCTL,
        &params,
        sizeof(TUN_REGISTER_RINGS),
        NULL,
        0,
        &bytes,
        NULL
    );

    if(ret == 0) {
        printf("Err: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return -2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that this code fails at `DeviceIoControl` with error 5, which corresponds to ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

I have no idea why that is happening as the program is already running with admin privileges and the device handle has been opened with the recommended attributes ([as you can see here](https://github.com/WireGuard/wintun#usage)). Sorry for the lack of extra information but I don't have much experience when it comes to windows drivers and don't know how to debug this any further.

I think the problem might have to do with this [check in the source code of the driver](https://github.com/WireGuard/wintun/blob/6d6e2190801b278b3aab84d910737925b8df5c2f/wintun.c#L862), as it appears to be stopping before checking the input buffer (it should rerurn INVALID_PARAMETER when I put garbage in the input buffer, but that doesn't happen).

Again, sorry if I misunderstood something or missed something critical but I am learning all of this as I go, thanks in advance!

Comment: from [TunInitializeDispatchSecurityDescriptor](https://github.com/WireGuard/wintun/blob/6d6e2190801b278b3aab84d910737925b8df5c2f/wintun.c#L784) clear visible that it allow `FILE_ALL_ACCESS` only for *LocalSystem* account. so only *LocalSystem* can send some ioctl to device. you and must got `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` if you run as admin but not *LocalSystem*

Comment: @RbMm Yes! You are right! I tried running the executable as LocalSystem and it finally worked, I guess it is there to make sure every application that talks to the driver is a service? Anyways, thank you!

Comment: @ErykSun - if i not mistake `FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT` ( `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` for win32) have effect only inside create/open file operation. but we have problem inside ioct which direct call `SeAccessCheck` [here](https://github.com/WireGuard/wintun/blob/6d6e2190801b278b3aab84d910737925b8df5c2f/wintun.c#L862) - so not help

Comment: in call `SeAccessCheck`  [here](https://github.com/WireGuard/wintun/blob/6d6e2190801b278b3aab84d910737925b8df5c2f/wintun.c#L862) at all not used `FileObject` from *Irp* but only security context of the calling thread. so anyway we need be *LocalSystem* at this point and SeBackupPrivilege and SeRestorePrivilege not help

Comment: @RbMm, sorry for the noise, clearly the previous `CreateFileW` call succeeded. It's weird to do another security check in the IOCTL. Typically it's up to the I/O manager, based on the access granted to the handle and the read/write access required by the IOCTL. I guess they need to work around the I/O manager's privilege check in `IoCreateFileEx` such that only SYSTEM will be allowed to use the IOCTL, but there are simpler ways to do that without this extra security descriptor. Maybe they provide a way for code to replace or extend the security descriptor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. As @RbMm described, the [code that creates the security descriptor](https://github.com/WireGuard/wintun/blob/6d6e2190801b278b3aab84d910737925b8df5c2f/wintun.c#L784) only allows access to LocalSystem. That means that it is the only account allowed to talk to the driver.